# Enable button if checkbox is selected in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, checkbox, disable

I want to enable a button if checkbox is selected or checked and disable it if unselected or unchecked.
I started all my application using kotlin.
if there is a way for doing somehting like that in kotlin please help!
and if there is no way in kotlin, show me a way for doing that wanted I mentioned above.
thanks to whome is trying to help.
[see this picture of my mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw3fQ.png)

here is my button and checkbox codes and :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llIAWith"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/i_agree_with"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/Middle_Gray"
            app:buttonTint="@color/Orange"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/terms_of_services"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/Orange"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
```

here is my kotlin codec :

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    initData()
}
private fun checkForInternet(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
    val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network) ?: return false
    return when{
        activeNetwork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
        activeNetwork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
        activeNetwork.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
private fun initData(){
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    clickListener()
    clickListenerFP()
}
private fun clickListenerFP(){
    binding.llFPassword.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this,ForgotPasswordActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
private fun clickListener(){
    binding.llDHAAccount.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this,RegisterActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
    binding.btnSIn.setOnClickListener{
        getUserData()
    }
}
private fun getUserData(){
    val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString()
    val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString()
    if(email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()){
        authUser(email, password)
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.all_inputs_are_required),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
private fun authUser(email: String, password: String){
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener{
            checkResult(it.isSuccessful)
        }
}
private fun checkResult(isSuccess: Boolean){
    if (checkForInternet(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).cancel()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.no_network_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    if(isSuccess){
        startActivity(Intent(this,DashboardActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.authentication_failed),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
private var backPressedTime:Long = 0
private lateinit var backToast:Toast
override fun onBackPressed() {
    backToast = Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.press_back_again_to_leave_the_app), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        backToast.cancel()
        super.onBackPressed()
        return
    } else {
        backToast.show()
    }
    backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

Comment: Whats so complicated about this ? have u tried anything ? Please read [ask] and add a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for your guidance sir, check the question now please!

Comment: basic understanding of the check box will let you do this try to read or watch some tutorial for android programming

Comment: but I found nothing in kotlin android and video tutorials. using KOTLIN. they are all in java and java codes not working, even not translating in android studio after writing them by tutorials I watched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is

```
binding.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    binding.btnSUp.isEnabled = isChecked
}
```